# I compiled LibreOffice on Windows using Cygwin, but after running 'C:/cygwin64/opt/lo/bin/make', I encountered numerous errors

Tags: cygwin, libreoffice

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cege8.png)

My machine is running Windows 11, and I'm using Visual Studio 2019 as the compiler. After numerous attempts, I'm still encountering this error, and currently, there is no solution.

I followed the compilation steps provided on the LibreOffice website completely.

Comment: The error deleting a file -> perhaps that is an antivirus problem.

Comment: Resource temporarily unavailable -> Problem with cygwin??

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio 2019 plays any role in the building. You are most likely using the gcc compiler from cygwin.